# How to display hidden files with Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

The "open file" dialog in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) is not showing hidden files. For example, when looking at my home directory, none of the `.` files are shown:

[image]

I did look through the `settings.json` file, but I did not find any applicable setting.  So - how do I configure Visual Studio Code properly?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

On Mac you can hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> in the *open file* dialog, to see hidden files.

([Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/557))

Comment: Yes it is a general mac thing.

Comment: The windows explorer has a `hidden items` setting under `View` (win 10). This enables showing hidden files everywhere. Not sure if you can toggle in a dialog  like on MacOS

Comment: Do you have any reference for "general mac things" keyboard shortcuts like this?

Comment: Wow. I've been using OS X for > 10 years and never knew that. Well played!

Comment: In case you are using Ubuntu, `Ctrl+O` and then right click on any of the file and  check "Show Hidden Files"

Comment: It doesn't do that for my mac pro, but its a cool short cut

Comment: On my Mac the hidden files were already visible in the Finder. I had to run the shortcut in the VS Code open file dialog, too, to see the hidden files there as well.

Comment: This change isn't persistent though. Isn't there a way to change this permanently so you don't have to `cmd+shift+.` every time?

Comment: **Don't forget the `SHIFT` key or else the dialog will close.**   Not that I would forget the `SHIFT` key, no, absolutely not.

Answer (score 150):

go to file -> preferences -> settings

and in the search bar, search for "files.exclude"

then delete whatever json setting that you don't want to hide that specific file

Comment: although not related to the `open file` window, this allows the file to be displayed on the side panel. I was looking for this answer, thanks!

Comment: Its Code -> Preferences -> Settings

Comment: Does not address the question.

Comment: @PaulChilds Yes it does. The topic was "How to display hidden files with Visual Studio Code". The top answers actually talk about displaying hidden files within certain OSes, namely Ubuntu and MacOS. This is the first one to talk about displaying hidden files in VSCode itself.

Comment: The question is clearly tagged macos. If perchance someone had an exclusion filter for hidden files then this would fix it, but not for the OP and the majority of people searching where it is due to the OS excluding them from the dialog.

Comment: The accepted solution talks about displaying the files in Mac OS Finder, not VSCode. Even if the files were still hidden in Finder, it would not effect them showing up in VSCode.

Answer (score 40):

Under Linux you can right click on files in the file selection window and check the "Show Hidden Files" checkbox.

Here's a screenshot from `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, VS Code v 1.52.1` after right clicking on the `header.php` file with *"Show Hidden Files"* option enabled:
[image: Linux VS Code Open File Dialogue Box Hidden Files Option]

Comment: That works, thanks! We can also type `.` to open a text dialog, which offers suggestions and autocomplete.

Comment: in other words File, Open File or File, Open Folder have the the option to right click which brings up a dialog box that includes Show Hidden File.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this solution is not persistent.
When opening back a file selection window the checkbox is unmarked.

Answer (score 27):

On Windows, in VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings.

Search *file.exclude* and hover over the hidden files you want to see and click the "**X**"

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question but useful anyways

Comment: Also don't forget to check "workspace" tab.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects This is the only answer that directly answers the question "How to display hidden files with Visual Studio Code"

Answer (score 14):

To display hidden .git directories in Visual Studio Code, do the following:

On Windows or Linux, select File → Preferences → Settings.

On Mac, select Code → Preferences → Settings.

In Visual Studio Code settings (Settings Editor), select Editor → File and scroll to (or search for) Exclude. Comment out the glob to exclude .git files (// **/.git). See the attached screenshot: [VS Code glob commenting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViKhq.png).

Also see [Visual Studio Code User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-editor). You will find the [default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings) on the page, which you could edit, but I chose to comment the glob out to conveniently hide these files later should I so desire.

[Visual Studio Code: Show hidden folders](https://imstudio.medium.com/visual-studio-code-show-hidden-folder-5fd0f01d3d5e) contains more information on the subject.

Comment: Does not answer the question which is about the open file dialog, not about what files are available in the explorer view

Comment: The last link is behind a paywall.

Answer (score 4):

Linux:

ctrl + ","

in search, type: "files exclude"

This shows all the patterns VS Code uses when deciding what to ignore. If you wanted to view a .git folder, you would simply remove that pattern from the list of patterns "**/.git". When you want to stop seeing it, just add that pattern back.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, open the .vscode folder in the explorer and comment out the file types you wish to see. There is no need to restart VS Code, just click the refresh explorer button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can edit your settings.json file directly to always show .git files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a quick way to toggle the visibility of hidden files, you can use an extension:

1. [Peek Hidden Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.toggle-hidden):

Toggle the visibility of excluded files by Explorer's context menu. I'm currently using this one.

2. [Make Hidden](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devine-davies.make-hidden):

Has a context menu option to hide selected items in Explorer.
Has an area to view hidden files.

3. [Explorer Exclude](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterSchmalfeldt.explorer-exclude):

Can control hidden file glob patterns without going to settings.json.
[preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keEzv.gif)

Answer (score -1):

In case if you are wondering how to do it in Visual Studio (NOT VS CODE) for mac.

1. Open Visual Studio in mac
2. Right click on your solution in Visual Studio
3. Display Options -> Show All Files

bin and obj files should be display.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

In menu *View* in Visual Studio Code, select *SCM* (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>),  right click on the Git icon, [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLKFx.png)  and select *Keep*.

Comment: How is "Keep" and hidden files related?

Comment: Where is the "Keep" item? Perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: This is only about hiding or showing the Source Control pane and has nothing to do with the question.