# Files starts with dot, don't show in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I create files .*babelrc* and .*gitignore*, but they don't show in VS Code project explorer. How  I can disable this hidding?
[Image of my Side Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkNMJ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display hidden files with visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779942/how-to-display-hidden-files-with-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @NicoHaase my trouble with explorer into vscode sidebar

Comment: how did you create dot(.) file with VSCode ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to settings (Mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) (Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>).
2. Search for `files.exclude`.
3. Ensure you do not have any glob patterns matching the files that are missing from the explorer.

Comment: Thank you, i accidentally added `**.*` pattern.

Comment: @jabacchetta, I am getting the issue in my VS code. If you have time then can you help me out with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665824/filename-prefix-showing-dot-and-underscore-when-open-in-visual-code-editor

Answer (score -1):

open settings --> files.exclude

add pattern:  **/.?*