# Dot and underscore showing with file name when open folder in VS code editor or Sublime editor

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I am using MacBook Air. I downloaded the visual code editor from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I tested the page and it's working.

I am getting an issue with the file name. I am getting the file name twice. The first file name starts from the  `._` and my second file name is correct.

**For example**.

I have the files below the files in my folder.

`about.php index.php`

When I open in visual studio code editor then I am getting

```
._about.php
._index.php
about.php
index.php
```

Please let me know what is the issue with my editor.

[image]

Would you help me out with this issue?

Now I am getting the same issue on the sublime editor.

Answer (score 6):

For VSCode users you actually can hide these files from sidebar :

Go to  Code > Preferences > Settings.
Search for files:exclude in the search at the top.
Add new pattern (any file which starts with ._):

```
**/._*
```

Here what it looks like on my machine

[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend. That was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is on a hard drive with exFAT format, Mac will automatically generate dot underscore file.  Dot underscore files are Mac system files and unrelated to visual studio code. They are the result of storing your files on a hard drive partition that does not support extended file attributes. They have likely always been there on your Mac, but since they are OS X system files, they were hidden

more details https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: Not on visual studio code, I am also getting this issue on sublime. I am getting this issue for the last 1 year but before I was not getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

find . -name "._*" -type f -delete

Comment: try this command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).