# VS Code duplicate files

Tags: visual-studio-code, duplicates

I have an issue with VS Code. Whenever I create a file it gets duplicate. I've tried to uninstall VS Code but the issue persists. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: VS Code duplicate files]

Comment: who creates all these `_` files? try with all extensions disabled

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60665824/11107541. see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980/479746 cc. @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

If the files do show up even in other text editors and file explorer then I would suggest you to uninstall some npm packages that you've installed and see if that changes anything.

Simply use `npm list -g` in terminal or cmd to show all of the packages that you've installed and use `npm uninstall -g packageName`.

If that doesn't work either, reinstall Node.js.