# Failed to send activity: bot returned an error 502 404

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to deploy the [ms teams auth](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) bot to azure. The bot gives a welcome message when I tested it using the bot framework emulator. Then I ran [these steps](https://aka.ms/azuredeployment) to deploy my bot to azure. During the deployment steps, I used the same app id and password throughout the whole process. Then I tested it on azure and it just fails:

[image]

I look at my browser's network requests and I see this:

```
HTTP POST: https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/JYtg14OvcjS7FiNwCMXzH1-g/activities
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BotError",
    "message": "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"
  },
  "httpStatusCode": 404
}
```

I streamed my application logs and it gave me a big HTML response you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/AskYous/ff0b0f4432d44c30558668cb694d2eab). But it's just a 404 page response.

I tried to run this in my bot emulator, pointing to the bot in production and it gave a 404 response as well:

[image]

### Edit:

1. I just tried to [redeploy my bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=erg%2Ccsharp) but got the same results when testing my bot.
2. After running all the [deployment steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=erg%2Ccsharp), I never had a web.config file. Though testing it in my bot emulator locally works fine.
3. Here is a screenshot of my resource group, which has 3 resources: [image]
4. Here is a screenshot after running the [pre-deploy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=erg%2Ccsharp#retrieve-or-create-necessary-iiskudu-files). It doesn't generate a web.config file, but it generates a .deployment file: [image]
5. The app ID is the same in app registrations portal in azure, and the same in my appsettings.json file, and the same when I ran the [deployment command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=erg%2Ccsharp#create-azure-resources-1).

### Edit 2:

1. Here is how I zipped my project: [image]
2. On Azure, I'm not able to view my code while I remember that I used to do it before. Perhaps it's because on Azure, I only have a Bot Channels Registration but I don't have a Web App Bot. Is that a problem?

### Edit 3:

1. I noticed I **did not** include the `.deployment` file when I zipped the contents. (The file explorer was hiding the file.) So now I included it in my zipped contents and redeployed by bot again. (Unfortunately, the bot is still behaving the same.)
2. Here are the new contents of /dev/wwwroot/: [image]
3. Here is my app registration (I tried toggling both account types instead of re-recreating it through command line, still same bot behavior):
   [image]
4. The `.deployment` file was zipped. My mac just didn't show it. I updated the screenshot to show my .deployment file above.

Comment: I see this message in the logs: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`. That's an odd one; I've only seen it when we have service issues, but it normally fixes itself. Can you try deleting these Azure services and deploying again? If it still doesn't work, please update your question with a screenshot of your Resource Group resources.

Comment: And can you confirm that you ran [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg%2Ccsharp#retrieve-or-create-necessary-iiskudu-files): `az bot prepare-deploy --lang Csharp --code-dir "." --proj-file-path "MyBot.csproj"`. If you're missing the `web.config` file, it's a good indication you missed this step.

Comment: Can you also confirm that you have [an App Registration](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade) that matches the appId listed for your Web App Bot service and that their names match?

Comment: Hello @mdrichardson-MSFT. I answered your questions in my post. See the edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPs issue ended up being that they need to make their App Registration available for ALL accounts, including personal. To do so, follow [these steps](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1366#issuecomment-479087524)

I'll keep the answer for posterity, but if you're running into this issue, my comments provide good troubleshooting steps.

---

Aha! The issue was [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg%2Ccsharp#zip-up-the-code-directory-manually). You need to zip up the **contents** of the project folder and not the folder itself.

This:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

When you deploy, your folder structure will look like this:

[image]

You aren't the first person to run into this. I've [created a PR to clarify this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/pull/1306). Let me know if you think the change I made should say something else.

Sidenote: The `web.config` is created upon deployment. My mistake with that comment.

Comment: I apologize for the trouble but I don't think this is the problem. I edited my post to include how I zipped my content (and not the folder itself) and I included another piece of information: I have a bot channels registration but I do not have a web app bot. Do I need one? I followed the deployment steps but it didn't create a web app bot in my azure.

Comment: @AskYous You are correct. I sure feel dumb. Misinterpreted your folder structure image as 
coming from your Azure App Service files, not VS Code. When deployed, I also have a Bot Channels Registration. Can you screenshot the folder structure of `https://<yourBot>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/` and edit it into your post? In `Your App Registration > Authentication`, do you [see this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40401643/61963501-94e1a000-af80-11e9-8460-d76a076262a3.png)? If not, [try this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2358#issuecomment-517336356)

Comment: @AskYous Wait a minute....I don't see your `.deployment` file getting zipped. I don't even see it in your directory. You either missed the `prepare-deploy` step or VS Code is hiding your `.*` files. If that isn't getting zipped, this is **definitely** the problem. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780050/10860086)

Comment: You're right. The file explorer was hiding the `.deployment` file. I fixed it and re-deployed it but the bot still behaves the same way. See my updated post.

Comment: @AskYous It's my understanding that it *must* support personal accounts (because it goes through Directline). [Try this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1366#issuecomment-479087524)

Comment: This was the issue. I did what the post said to do and now I'm finally getting some response from the bot and it asks me to log in now! Though it's taking me to a login page that just says "Bad Request" but I might open a new SO post if I can't get it working.

Comment: Haha. There's always something...But yeah, please open a new SO post. Likely has to do with your OAuth settings

Comment: @AskYous Updated my answer to reflect the final verdict. Thanks for being willing to troubleshoot!